# AWS Autoscaling Not Cloning Correct Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-elb

I have an instance in AWS that I set up my entire environment (I'll call it my ready instance) on and is running perfectly. I then created a load balancer (ELB) with an autoscaling policy.

When I created a load balancer with an autoscaling policy (min of 2 instances), 2 instances sprung up. The instances were empty, however. For the launch configuration, I specified my ready instance AMI. Isn't this supposed to tell the autoscaling policy which instance to clone? In this case, shouldn't my ready instance be cloned into them and they should have the same content?

Comment: Did you create a new AMI once you set up your instance? Or did you specify the base AMI? AMI's only serve to create the initial copy the instance when launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instances are not created based on a clone of a running instance, but rather just the disk image stored in the AMI.  It might be a case where you need to create a new AMI from your running instance and use that AMI as the basis for your autoscaling group.

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out on my own. The AMI of my instance was Amazon Ubutnu ami ID.

Answer (score 2):

once upon a time even I was this phase of my life.Basically it will just the boot the AMI which you have specified in your as configuration. If your AMI has got old code, then it will boot and serve your client from the out-dated code. Do solve this you can automate the code management process, all you have to do is boot the new ami with a user-data script which will perfom certain actions during the boot. Using user-data script you can automate this process. Autoscaling configuration also have a provision to accept the user-script data.

Comment: See the accepted answer. I also had to run a few cron jobs and scripts to achieve what I needed. Used Python Boto for set up.